# Create aesthetically pleasing ring chart programmatically in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. Please point me to the right direction if it isn't!

I found a LaTeX resume template here:
https://github.com/opensorceror/Data-Engineer-Resume-LaTeX

Although the `Skills` bubbles and `Interests` bars are being created programmatically, the `Languages` ring chart looks like a simple .png image that has been inserted into the document.

Is it possible to create a replica of this chart *programmatically* in LaTeX? A simple code example would be appreciated!

**Note:** The reason I wish to create it programmatically is because employers may use automatic parsers to identify skills keywords in a resume, and such keywords would be impossible to extract from a .png image.

Comment: Someone may be able to help you here, potentially better to post on the dedicated LaTeX stack exchange. http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll post it there. Should this post be deleted?

Comment: Not necessarily, it still may be helpful. Plus you're more likely to get an answer if you use both sites :)